# Accessing constants from deep nested module

Tags: ruby, namespaces

I have the following module structure:

```
-->Analytics (module)
    --> Reporting
        --> Metrics
            --> Computed

-->Content (class)
```

Within `Computed`, I have some module constant `FOO`. There are a number of methods in `Content` that reach down into `Computed` and access `FOO`. Currently, the way this is being done is:

```
#content.rb
...
def do_something
    ...
    foo = Analytics::Reporting::Metrics::Computed::FOO
    ...
end
```

What is the best practice for accessing deep nested module constants or variables? I cannot namespace `Content` any differently. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once in the class body of `Content`, do this:

```
include Analytics::Reporting::Metrics::Computed
```

Then, you will have access to `FOO` without explicit namespace.

```
module A
  module B
    module C
      module D
        FOO = "This is FOO from A::B::C::D"
      end
    end
  end
end

class E
  include A::B::C::D
  p FOO
end
# => "This is FOO from A::B::C::D"
```

Answer (score 1):

While this is my opinion, I would consider storing that at the config level, perhaps using [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) or similar means, especially if it could be accessed by many different classes.